# Biblatex: Modify maxcitenames to work in three cases

Tags: biblatex, author-number

Classically `maxcitenames` in `biblatex` is set to something like `\usepackage[maxcitenames=2,style=authoryear]{biblatex}` to get the following citations:

- One author name if there is only one author
- Two author names if there are two authors
- Two author names + et.al if there are more than two authors

Is there a way to modify `maxcitenames` in a way that I get

- One author name if there is only one author
- Two author names if there are two authors
- **First** author name + et.al if there are more than two authors

This would require to count how many authors are in an bib-entry and decide which of the three cases is applicable.

I am happy to hack a bit myself if someone can give me at least a starting point. Handling author lists in `biblatex` does not seem trivial to me.

Comment: I think it already works as you want.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to achieve:

- One author name if there is only one author
- Two author names if there are two authors
- First author name + et.al if there are more than two authors

then

```
\usepackage[maxcitenames=2,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

is correct already, while if you want to achieve:

- One author name if there is only one author
- Two author names if there are two authors
- Two author names + et.al if there are more than two authors

then you have to add `mincitenames=2`:

```
\usepackage[mincitenames=2,maxcitenames=2,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

Comment: `mincitenames` was the answer I was looking for as well.

Comment: Mine didn't work until I combined this with @Holger 's answer: \usepackage[mincitenames=2,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=minyear,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes you don't get the expected result because biblatex is trying to be smart about disambiguating the labels, e.g., if you are citing two different four-author papers in your document that would be cited as "Cotton et al. 1999" and "Cotton et al. 2001". To deactivate this behavior entirely, use `uniquelist=false`. You can also set it so that it disambiguates only if the year of the two publications is also identical:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,uniquelist=minyear]{biblatex}
```

Comment: I now recommend biblatex-chicago, which seems to have more reasonable default settings for the authoryear citation style: `\usepackage[authordate,useprefix=true,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}`

Comment: Thank you! After two hours trying to get it fixed your hint was a blessing!

Answer (score 2):

If I compile the example below I get your required result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[maxcitenames=2,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{weinberg}%one author

\cite{bertram}%two authors

\cite{companion}%three authors

\cite{cotton}%four authors

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image]