# biblatex: More than three auhors > et al. in IEEE (conflicting options)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

How can I force to show citations for three or more authors as et al. http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf

Like,

- A. Mike, B. Smith, C. Oliver, "blah blah", in Proc. ABC 2001 , ...(**original**)
- A. Mike et al., "blah blah", in Proc. ABC 2001, ...  (**desired**)

there is an answer here: [Biblatex: Modify maxcitenames to work in three cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121625/biblatex-modify-maxcitenames-to-work-in-three-cases)

it works with style=authoryear. But when I add style=ieee,

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, maxnames=3]{biblatex}
```

it does say "conflicting options (maxcitenames/mincitenames), thus does not work. I noticed in ieee.cbx file, there are some parameters set as below

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
    maxcitenames = 3,
    minnames     = 3,
    sorting      = none
}
```

According to above there should not be more than three names in references, right? But I am getting more than three names in references. I do not see any "et al." in references, regardless of proceedings or book articles.

My solution was to edit ieee.cbx and ieee.bbx file, and comment out the paremeters, that works but I was wondering if there is another solution that does not require editing the files.

Comment: Do you think your problem could be related to the `uniquelist` feature? (I think so, but can't test anything here.) As in [Set limit to one author when using “et al.” in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864) and [biblatex is ignoring maxcitenames](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114442/35864). Did you use `uniquelist=minyear` or anything else or nothing? (One question you linked to might suggest you use `uniquelist=minyear`, but in your code snippets and question I can't find any further mention of `uniquelist`.)

Comment: @moewe yes that solved it, I had been using uniquename=false, but uniquelist works

Comment: Fine, I voted to close as a duplicate then.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this question: IMO, it is not a duplicate. In order to get this working and not edit the ieee files, simply override both maxnames/maxcitenames and minnames/mincitenames settings to prevent a conflict, e.g. `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}`