# Different style of citation for two and more author biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

In `biblatex` citation, I want to put `and' in between author name if number of author is 2.

Otherwise for more number of authors the citation output will `first author et al., year'.

For example 
if bib file contains :

*@article{two_name,
  title={ABC},
  author={First, name and Second, name},
  year={2002}
}
@article{three_name,
  title={ABC2},
  author={First, name and Second, name and third, name},
  year={2002}
}*

Then the citation should result in

- First and Second, 2002 for `\cite{two_name}`
- First et al., 2002 for

  \cite{three_name}

**NOTe:** `maxcitenames=2` option of `biblatex` produce the first output correct. However, the second citation is rendered as First, Second et al., 2002.

Comment: What bibliography style do you use? Have a look here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121625/biblatex-modify-maxcitenames-to-work-in-three-cases. I'd like to test it, but you have to produce a minmal working example.

Comment: Have a look here too https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69030/94317, it could be related to disambiguation purposes.

Comment: @omission My options were    [hyperref=true,
            backref=true,
            style=authoryear-comp,
            citereset=chapter,
            maxcitenames=2,
            maxbibnames=100,
            block=none,
   sorting=ynt]{biblatex}